# Java Breadth First Search - 8 Slider

Tags: java, algorithm, breadth-first-search

The question is this, breadth first search needs to sort a board array of 9 values.   1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0.. In order, was told not to modify most of the existing code, and to add BFS and other statements in numerous class files.  The run time is giving 1,2,5,3,4,8,6,7,0. It is moving the 0 properly, but as to the path, not sure what to add to the existing code in order to resolve this so that the pathing and numbers resolve.

```java
  while (!frontier.isEmpty()) {
    cur = frontier.remove();
    if (cur.isGoal()) {
      return cur;
    } else if (cur.getDepth() < 15) {
      visited.add(cur);
      for (Node s : cur.expand()) {
        if (!visited.contains(s)) {
          s.setParent(cur);
          s.setDepth(cur.getDepth() + 1);
          frontier.add(s);
          numNodesExplored++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
    return null;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You are not returning anything if you don't find your "goal". Also, this is a search why should it be sorted?

Comment: Could you add an expected output? You talking about a sorting while BFS is a search algorithm

Comment: could you please edit you code - there is a `return` missing..

Comment: I'm sorry but this method can't give you a list as result because it only returns *one* `Node`. It looks like you are execut an other method to find a path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention in the comments that you aspect a output like `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0`. This is not possible with the method `runBFS`. When you look at the method signature `Node runBFS(Node start)` you can see that this method returns a `Node` and not a List of Nodes.

Additional to that you have a logical error. In the bellow code-block you can see that you add to a `Node s` his parent to `s`. With other words: `s` is his own parent.

```java
if (!explored.contains(s)) {
    s.setParent(s);   // here you add the wrong parent - it should be s.setParent(cur)
    s.setDepth(cur.getDepth() + 1);
    frontier.add(s);
    numNodesExplored++;
}
```

Just change the line to `s.setParent(cur)`. `cur` is the `Node` you are looking for his siblings.